# How do I remove duplicate numbers from my hand of cards?

Tags: python

So i have my hand of cards that i randomly dealt from a deck but i need to remove the duplicate numbers in my hand. I have no idea where to start.

this is an example of what my hand would look like before removing the pairs:

```
l=['6♠', '6♣', '7♢', '10♣', '8♣', '2♣', '9♠', '8♢', '7♠', 'K♢', '9♡', 'Q♡', '10♢', '2♠', 'K♡', '2♢', '3♢', 'Q♢', '6♡', '4♣', 'A♡', '4♡', 'A♠', 'A♣', 'J♣', 'Q♠']
```

and this is what i've tried:

```
no_pairs=[]

l.sort()
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in (i+1, len(l)):
        if i[-2] not in j:
            no_pairs.append(i)
```

when i do this, it keeps saying

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: it should be `l[-2]` instead of `i[-2]` i guess

Comment: Strange that you accepted an answer that does like line, but was posted minutes after me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Strip the final character when iterating through the list of strings.

If you're just looking for the number, ignoring the suit, then you just need to strip the suit from the number before comparing it to an array of the numbers you've already sorted, and then adding both the stripped value to the array of numbers, and the original value to the final output. This should work:

```
l.sort()
sorted_num = []
final = []
for i in l:
  if i[:-1] not in sorted_num:
    sorted_num.append(i[:-1])
    final.append(i)
```

When run, this gives the value of final as:

```
['10♢', '2♠', '3♢', '4♡', '6♠', '7♠', '8♢', '9♠', 'A♠', 'J♣', 'K♡', 'Q♠']
```

Comment: thank you so much!! i appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` is an int, you can achieve `i[2]` (for the error). Then I really don't know where your code was going, so I didn't try to fix I wrote a new one.

---

I'd suggest you keep track of the numbers you already added, so that you know if you add the card or not

```
l = ['6♠', '6♣', '7♢', '10♣', '8♣', '2♣', '9♠', '8♢', '7♠', 'K♢', '9♡', 'Q♡', '10♢',
     '2♠', 'K♡', '2♢', '3♢', 'Q♢', '6♡', '4♣', 'A♡', '4♡', 'A♠', 'A♣', 'J♣', 'Q♠']

no_pairs = []
nb_cards = set()

for card in l:
    nb_card = card[:-1]
    if nb_card not in nb_cards:
        nb_cards.add(nb_card)
        no_pairs.append(card)

print(no_pairs)  # ['6♠', '7♢', '10♣', '8♣', '2♣', '9♠', 'K♢', 'Q♡', '3♢', '4♣', 'A♡', 'J♣']
```

You can replace the `set` by a `list`, but that woul dbe just less performant

Answer (score 0):

Check for the occurrence of each element in the list, and append only if occurs once.

```
l=['6♠', '6♣', '7♢', '10♣', '8♣', '2♣', '9♠', '8♢', '7♠', 'K♢', '9♡', 'Q♡', '10♢', '2♠', 'K♡', '2♢', '3♢', 'Q♢', '6♡', '4♣', 'A♡', '4♡', 'A♠', 'A♣', 'J♣', 'Q♠']

no_pairs=[]

for i in set(l):
   if l.count(i)==1:
      no_pairs.append(i)
```

Comment: `l` list is already unique, also `set(l)` is a better code for what you do (if it was needed)

Comment: Yeah agree @azro. Thanks

Comment: is there anyway to do it without set? I super appreciate you guys for the help. I've been scratching my head since midnight

Comment: @heyhoezay Yeah, there is. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get first character of items with `item[0]`, then check it is a number with `num.isdigit()` method and add it to `no_pairs` list.

```
l=['6♠', '6♣', '7♢', '10♣', '8♣', '2♣', '9♠', '8♢', '7♠', 'K♢', '9♡', 'Q♡', '10♢', '2♠', 'K♡', '2♢', '3♢', 'Q♢', '6♡', '4♣', 'A♡', '4♡', 'A♠', 'A♣', 'J♣', 'Q♠']


no_pairs = []

for item in l:
    num = item[0]
    if num.isdigit():
        num = int(num)
        no_pairs.append(int(num))

print(no_pairs)
```

```
#output :
[6, 6, 7, 1, 8, 2, 9, 8, 7, 9, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4]
```